# MySQL Installation Error when Initializing database

Tags: mysql, database, failed-installation

This is the error log I get when I try to install MySQL Server 5.7 via MySQL Installer- Community.

The installer fails when Applying Configurations, it fails specifically on the Initializing of the Database.

> Beginning configuration step: Initializing Database
>   Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
>   Starting process for MySQL Server 5.7.21...
>   Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on...
>   mysqld: Character set '0.0' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\charsets\Index.xml' file
>   2018-03-26T07:25:55.410217Z 0 [Warning] option 'read_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 8192
>   2018-03-26T07:25:55.410294Z 0 [Warning] option 'read_rnd_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
>   2018-03-26T07:25:55.410357Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
>   2018-03-26T07:25:55.410372Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
>   2018-03-26T07:25:55.412580Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
>   Process for mysqld, with ID 4880, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
>   Failed to start process for MySQL Server 5.7.21.
>   Database initialization failed.
>   Ended configuration step: Initializing Database

Comment: Did you have any luck? I have the same issue. Mysql 5.7.21

Comment: Sorry man, I got nothing. Fortunately I got this error on my laptop and not my actual desktop that I'm using. Hope someone answers this soon though.

Comment: I fixed the issue by resetting my laptop.